# LLMChain response is empty but no error is thrown

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, langchain, large-language-model

The method `use_langchain`, which is part of larger code base runs successfully without any errors. The model is deployed via Hugging Face Inference Endpoints. The problem is that when I'm trying to **print the generated output from the model, nothing happens**. The code just prints the prompt, then prints `LLMChain run completed` and terminates, printing nothing for the output. I don't understand why I'm unable to get the output. I cannot debug for hours because Inference Endpoints are costly to run.

```
def use_langchain(hf_endpoint, patient_data: str, field: str, list_of_options: str):
    template = '''{114 words, 828 characters prompt}'''

    prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["prompt_patient_data", "prompt_field", "prompt_list_of_options"],
                            template=template)

    llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=hf_endpoint)
    response = llm_chain.run(prompt_patient_data=patient_data, prompt_field=field, prompt_list_of_options=list_of_options)

    print(llm_chain.prompt)
    print(response)
    print("LLMChain run completed.")
    return response
```

Comment: According to this; https://docs.langchain.com/docs/components/chains/llm-chain there should be a `OutputParser`. Check this link too; https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/6013#issuecomment-1586670460

Comment: @doneforaiur thank you. I've also just discovered that the model works correctly for short prompts. However, I my problem is actually encountered when the input prompt gets large. I'll look into parsers, probably the output is large as well so needs to be broken into chunks.

Comment: @doneforaiur OutputParsers are optional and exist to tailor the output to a specific format if I understand correctly. They are not required to simply receive the output [check docs](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/prompts/output_parsers)

Answer (score 1):

```
import langchain

langchain.debug = True
```

this will print all the intermediate steps on the chain. it is very detailed debugging